# is there any problem with using provider for CRUD operation in flutter that cause overwriting?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, crud, provider

I'm making a simple to do list mobile application with Flutter by using Provider as a state management and shared preference as a local storage. And I've achieved the create part, read and the delete part, but struggling with the update part of my task. The problem I'm encountering is, when I try to edit/update any task except the first index task, it overwrite the first index task with the new title and description I gave to the edited task and also that task that I was trying to edit is exists with its old value but the edit functionality works fine only for the first index task. in order for you to better understand let me share you some of my codes that I covered so far:

This is my Task model class:

```
`class Task {
  String id;
  String title;
  String description;
  DateTime dueDate;
  bool isCompleted;
  bool isFavorite;

  Task({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.dueDate,
    required this.isCompleted,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other is Task &&
        id == other.id &&
        title == other.title &&
        description == other.description &&
        dueDate == other.dueDate &&
        isCompleted == other.isCompleted &&
        isFavorite == other.isFavorite;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return id.hashCode ^
        title.hashCode ^
        description.hashCode ^
        dueDate.hashCode ^
        isCompleted.hashCode ^
        isFavorite.hashCode;
  }

  factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Task(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      description: json['description'],
      dueDate: DateTime.parse(json['dueDate']),
      isCompleted: json['isCompleted'] ?? false,
      isFavorite: json['isFavorite'] ?? false,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
      'description': description,
      'dueDate': dueDate.toIso8601String(),
      'isCompleted': isCompleted,
      'isFavorite': isFavorite,
    };
  }
} 

And this is my TodoProvider class:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/model/task.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class TodoProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Task> _tasks = [];
  List<Task> _favoriteTasks = [];
  SharedPreferences? _prefs;

  List<Task> get tasks => _tasks;
  List<Task> get favoriteTasks => _favoriteTasks;

  TodoProvider() {
    _loadTasks();
  }

  Future<void> _loadTasks() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final tasksJson = _prefs!.getString('tasks');
    final favoriteTasksJson = _prefs!.getString('favoriteTasks');

    if (tasksJson != null) {
      final List<dynamic> decodedTasks = jsonDecode(tasksJson);
      _tasks = decodedTasks.map((decodedTask) => Task.fromJson(decodedTask)).toList();
    }

    if (favoriteTasksJson != null) {
      final List<dynamic> decodedFavoriteTasks = jsonDecode(favoriteTasksJson);
      _favoriteTasks = decodedFavoriteTasks.map((decodedTask) => Task.fromJson(decodedTask)).toList();
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> _saveTasks() async {
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> encodedTasks =
        _tasks.map((task) => task.toJson()).toList();
    final tasksJson = jsonEncode(encodedTasks);
    await _prefs!.setString('tasks', tasksJson);
  }

  Future<void> _saveFavoriteTasks() async {
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> encodedFavoriteTasks =
        _favoriteTasks.map((task) => task.toJson()).toList();
    final favoriteTasksJson = jsonEncode(encodedFavoriteTasks);
    await _prefs!.setString('favoriteTasks', favoriteTasksJson);
  }

  void addTask(Task task) {
    if (!_tasks.contains(task)) {
      _tasks.add(task);
      _saveTasks();
    }

    if (task.isFavorite && !_favoriteTasks.contains(task)) {
      _favoriteTasks.add(task);
      _saveFavoriteTasks();
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeTask(Task task) {
    _tasks.remove(task);
    _favoriteTasks.removeWhere((favoriteTask) => favoriteTask.id == task.id);
    _saveTasks();
    _saveFavoriteTasks();
    notifyListeners();
  }

void updateTask(Task updatedTask) {
  final existingTaskIndex = _tasks.indexWhere((task) => task.id == updatedTask.id);
  
  if (existingTaskIndex != -1) {
    final existingTask = _tasks[existingTaskIndex];
    final existingTaskIsFavorite = existingTask.isFavorite;

    _tasks[existingTaskIndex] = updatedTask;

    if (existingTaskIsFavorite) {
      final existingFavoriteIndex = _favoriteTasks.indexWhere((task) => task.id == updatedTask.id);
      if (existingFavoriteIndex != -1) {
        _favoriteTasks[existingFavoriteIndex] = updatedTask;
      }
    }

    _saveTasks();
    _saveFavoriteTasks();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

  void completeTask(int index, bool isCompleted) {
    final task = _tasks[index];
    task.isCompleted = isCompleted;

    if (task.isFavorite) {
      final correspondingTask = _favoriteTasks.firstWhere((t) => t.id == task.id);
      correspondingTask.isCompleted = isCompleted;
    }

    _saveTasks();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<Task> getTasksForToday() {
    final today = DateTime.now();
    final todayTasks = _tasks.where((task) {
      final taskDate = task.dueDate;
      return taskDate.year == today.year &&
          taskDate.month == today.month &&
          taskDate.day == today.day;
    }).toList();

    return todayTasks;
  }

  bool areAllTasksCompleted() {
    return _tasks.isNotEmpty && _tasks.every((task) => task.isCompleted);
  }

  void toggleAllTasksCompleted(bool isCompleted) {
    for (var task in _tasks) {
      task.isCompleted = isCompleted;
    }

    for (var favoriteTask in _favoriteTasks) {
      favoriteTask.isCompleted = isCompleted;
    }

    _saveTasks();
    _saveFavoriteTasks();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool isTaskFavorite(Task task) {
    return _favoriteTasks.contains(task);
  }

  void toggleFavorite(Task task) {
    if (_favoriteTasks.contains(task)) {
      _favoriteTasks.remove(task);
    } else {
      _favoriteTasks.add(task);
    }
    _saveFavoriteTasks();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getTasksCountForToday() {
    final today = DateTime.now();
    final todayTasks = _tasks.where((task) {
      final taskDate = task.dueDate;
      return taskDate.year == today.year &&
          taskDate.month == today.month &&
          taskDate.day == today.day;
    }).toList();

    return todayTasks.length;
  }

  List<Task> getUpcomingTasks() {
    final tomorrow = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1));
    final upcomingTasks = _tasks.where((task) {
      final taskDate = task.dueDate;
      return taskDate.isAfter(tomorrow) && taskDate.difference(tomorrow).inDays <= 2;
    }).toList();

    return upcomingTasks;
  }
}

And this is my EditTaskScreen class:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/model/task.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../provider/todoprovider.dart';

class EditTaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Task task;

  const EditTaskScreen({Key? key, required this.task}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _EditTaskScreenState createState() => _EditTaskScreenState();
}

class _EditTaskScreenState extends State<EditTaskScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _titleController.text = widget.task.title;
    _descriptionController.text = widget.task.description;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _titleController.dispose();
    _descriptionController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Task',
           style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white54,
          ),
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          color: Colors.white54,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
             Text(
              'Title',
               style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Color(0xFF2980B9),
                        fontSize: 16,
                  ),
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _titleController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter title here',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
             Text(
              'Description',
              style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Color(0xFF2980B9),
                        fontSize: 16,
                  ),
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _descriptionController,
              maxLines: 5,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter description here',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          ],
        ),
      )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0A4C71),
        foregroundColor: Colors.white54,
        onPressed: () {
              Task updatedTask = Task(
                id: widget.task.id,
                title: _titleController.text.trim(),
                description: _descriptionController.text.trim(),
                dueDate: widget.task.dueDate,
                isCompleted: widget.task.isCompleted,
                isFavorite: widget.task.isFavorite,
              );

              final todoProvider = Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context, listen: false);
              todoProvider.updateTask(updatedTask);
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text(
                    'Task updated successfully.',
                    style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A4C71),
                ),
              );
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
        child: const Icon(Icons.save),
      ),
    );
  }
}

And this is my TaskListWidget class:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/model/task.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/provider/todoprovider.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/screen/edittaskscreen.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/screen/taskdetailscreen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class TaskListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Task> tasks;

  const TaskListWidget({Key? key, required this.tasks}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final taskProvider = Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context);
    final List<Task> tasks = taskProvider.tasks;

    return tasks.isEmpty
        ?  Center(
           child: Text(
                  'Make Your First Todo.',
                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                    textStyle:  const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 20,
                 ),
             ),
           ),
          )
    : ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
      itemCount: tasks.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final task = tasks[index];
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.white70,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            elevation: 20,
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        TaskDescriptionScreen(task: task),
                  ),
                );
              },
              title: Text(
                task.title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  decoration: task.isCompleted
                      ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                      : TextDecoration.none,
                ),
              ),
              leading: Checkbox(
                value: task.isCompleted,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  final taskProvider =
                      Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context, listen: false);
                  taskProvider.completeTask(index, value ?? false);
                  _showRemainingTasksSnackBar(context, taskProvider.tasks);

                },
              ),
              trailing: PopupMenuButton<String>(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.more_vert,
                  color: Colors.black26,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
                   const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                    value: 'edit',
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 125,
                      height: 40,
                    child: ListTile(
                          dense: true,
                          leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
                          title: Text('Edit'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                   const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                    value: 'delete',
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 125,
                      height: 40,
                    child: ListTile(
                      dense: true,
                      leading: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      title: Text('Delete'),
                    ),
                  ),
                   ),
                ],
                onSelected: (String value) {
                  if (value == 'edit') {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                            EditTaskScreen(task: task),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (value == 'delete') {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: const Text('Delete Task'),
                          content:
                              const Text('Are you sure you want to remove this task?'),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                              child: const Text('Cancel'),
                            ),
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                final taskProvider =
                                    Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context, listen: false);
                                taskProvider.removeTask(task);
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                  const SnackBar(
                                    content: Text(
                                      'Task deleted successfully',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.red, 
                                    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'OK',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red[400]),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 10,
                offset: const Offset(0, 10),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _showRemainingTasksSnackBar(BuildContext context, List<Task> tasks) {
  final remainingTasksCount = tasks.where((task) => !task.isCompleted).length;
  if (remainingTasksCount == 0) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('Congratulations! You have completed all tasks'),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      //behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
       // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      ),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  } else {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('$remainingTasksCount tasks remain'),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A4C71), 
      //behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      ),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
}

And Finally this is my HomePage class:

import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/provider/todoprovider.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/model/task.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/screen/searchtaskscreen.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/widget/appbardrawer.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/widget/tasklist.dart';
import 'package:my_todo/screen/addtaskscreen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool notificationShown = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final todoProvider = Provider.of<TodoProvider>(context, listen: false);
      final tasksCount = todoProvider.getTasksCountForToday();
      if (tasksCount > 0 && !notificationShown) {
        initializeNotifications();
        showNotification(tasksCount);
        setState(() {
          notificationShown = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void initializeNotifications() {
    AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      null,
      [
        NotificationChannel(
          channelKey: 'basic_channel',
          channelName: 'Basic notifications',
          channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic notifications',
          defaultColor: Colors.teal,
          ledColor: Colors.teal,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void showNotification(int tasksCount) async {
    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
        id: 0,
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        title: 'You have $tasksCount tasks for today',
        body: 'See the details in the Today option',
        payload: {'screen': 'today'},
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'My Todo',
             style: GoogleFonts.quicksand( 
              textStyle: TextStyle(
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,          
               color: Colors.white54,
               fontSize: 18,
             ),
           ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) => IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: Colors.white54,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
            },
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white54,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const SearchTaskScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Consumer<TodoProvider>(
            builder: (context, todoProvider, _) {
              final allTasksCompleted = todoProvider.areAllTasksCompleted();
              return IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  allTasksCompleted
                      ? Icons.check_box
                      : Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                  color: Colors.white54,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  todoProvider.toggleAllTasksCompleted(!allTasksCompleted);
                  _showRemainingTasksSnackBar(context, todoProvider.tasks);
  
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: const AppDrawer(),
      body: Consumer<TodoProvider>(
      builder: (context, todoProvider, _) {
        final List<Task> tasks = todoProvider.tasks;
        return TaskListWidget(
          tasks: tasks,
        );
      },
      ),  
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0A4C71),
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 6.0,
        hoverElevation: 8.0,
        focusElevation: 4.0,
        disabledElevation: 0.0,
        tooltip: 'Add',
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const TaskAddScreen(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/icons/addi1.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25,
          color: Colors.white54,
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
    void _showRemainingTasksSnackBar(BuildContext context, List<Task> tasks) {
  final remainingTasksCount = tasks.where((task) => !task.isCompleted).length;
  if (remainingTasksCount == 0) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('Congratulations! You have completed all tasks'),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green, 
      //behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
       // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      ),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  } else {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('$remainingTasksCount tasks remain'),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A4C71), 
      //behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      ),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
}`
```

So, I tried to modify my update method in my TodoProvider class many times if the problem is with it but I can't solve it.